# How does one sync live to dev datastores on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, synchronization, google-cloud-datastore

I've got some data up on Google App Engine's live datastore, but would like to have a local copy as well for local development.  What's the best way to do an occasional sync?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no trivial way to do this, but there are some possibilities:

- Use the official [bulk uploader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) (from the GAE-Python SDK) if your application is in Python (but not Django)
- Use [Gaebar](http://aralbalkan.com/1784) if your application is in Django
- Use the [Datanucleus REST API](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_1/rest/api.html) if your app is in Java

You can also try some other open source projects meant to solve this problem. [AppRocket](http://code.google.com/p/approcket/) was a promising one, but there's only one commiter to the project and there is no activity in the past months...

Also, star issues [59](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=59&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary%20Log%20Component) and [776](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=776&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary%20Log%20Component) to get this included officially by google.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I've messed with the bulk uploader, but it doesn't support setting key name at all.  Alas, my app is neither Django nor Java, so it looks like I'll have to work out some custom solution.  What a pain.

Comment: Good luck! I guess it will be tricky when dealing with primary keys (which in most projects are auto-generated).